# How does a struct pointer differentiate between the use of the same pointer?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

This is an example from geeks for geeks. The last example is  `root->left->left = new Node(4);` I was wondering how the left node retains its old value, and is able to connect to a new value using the same struct variable. Is each time the "new Node()" being called its creating another block of memory or what? I am confused.

```
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;

    // val is the key or the value that
    // has to be added to the data part
    Node(int val)
    {
        data = val;

        // Left and right child for node
        // will be initialized to null
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{

    /*create root*/
    struct Node* root = new Node(1);
    /* following is the tree after above statement

            1
            / \
        NULL NULL
    */

    root->left = new Node(2);
    root->right = new Node(3);
    /* 2 and 3 become left and right children of 1
                    1
                / \
                2    3
            / \  / \
            NULL NULL NULL NULL
    */

    root->left->left = new Node(4);
    /* 4 becomes left child of 2
            1
            /    \
        2    3
        / \  / \
        4 NULL NULL NULL
        / \
    NULL NULL
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what `new` does. Is there something in your C++ textbook's explanation of how `new` works and what it does that's unclear to you? Your question is unclear.

Comment: So maybe I am unclear on how the pointer to of ```Node* root``` But when ```struct Node* root = new Node(1);``` This will return a pointer to the memory location of Node(1) right? So when we keep allocating memory each time, does that create new blocks of memory being pointed to each time, or does it preserve the same memory address? If it preserves the same memory address, where are Node(2), Node(3), Node(4) being stored, and root->left->left = new Node(4); saying the root-> is now bound to the first instance of ```left``` when going down the tree?

Comment: Again, how `new` works is explained in every C++ textbook. How does your textbook explain `new`, can you  quote a brief excerpt that's unclear to you?

Comment: @Zboyz Um... if I read your comment correctly, you are asking which of two things happens. For the second option ("preserve the same memory address", whatever that means), you come up with a list of reasons why that option cannot be the case. So why the confusion? All signs point to the first option, no? You seem to already know the answer. Ignore the creation of your imagination (a.k.a. the second option) and go with the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root->left = new Node(2);` and `root->left->left = new Node(4);` both create new Node objects in memory so you're question

> Is each time the "new Node()" being called its creating another block of memory or what?

is somewhat accurate.

Initially, root is a Node object with a data value of 1 and a left value of NULL.  It's left pointer points to nothing.  The statement `root->left = new Node(2);` sets the roots left pointer to the address of a new Node.  This new node has the data value of 2 and a left value of NULL.  Imagine this new node has a name and it's name is A. The expression `root->left->left` evaluates left to right so `root->left` is the node A and thus the expression becomes `A->left`.  `A->left` is currently NULL.  After execution of `root->left->left = new Node(4);` A's left pointer now points to a new Node with data value of 4.

Comment: So basically a block of memory is being allocated each time new is being called for a separate node ```root``` bound 2 the lets say "A" and that link is established, so what is really is happening is instead of ```root->left->left = new Node(4);``` I can interpret it as ```root->A->left-> new Node(4);``` And now the new ```left``` is 4 and has a left and right null pointer?

Comment: A block or memory is not strictly correct but yes, each time new is called it creates a new Node object. My substitution was only to try and show the left to right evaluation. root->left->left is easier to think of as A->left where A = root->left.  Each object has it's own left so there are 4 Node objects in the example.  root, root->left, root->right, root->left->left.  root->left is it's own object, and root->left->left is root->left's left.  This is easier to explain with pictures.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks. Its harder for me to get without seeing ```this``` but I suppose that implied with the arrow operator? Regardless I get it now Thank you.